# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occured in CS

Tags: unhandled

I've got this problem, I am trying to make a SteamBot for myself in MC Visual Studio 2015.
When I run my program I encounter the following error :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in CSharpTradeOffers.dll

A screenshot is available here :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGSLr.jpg

Comment: How many elements is in the variable split?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=DonationBot..rar here is my full work,i hope you can help me :)